# Python data extraction and search

Tags: python, parsing

I have data in a file in this format:

```
+1 1:4 2:11 3:3 4:11 5:1 6:13 7:4 8:2 9:2 10:13
-1 1:2 2:7 3:4 4:12 5:3 6:4 7:3 8:12 9:2 10:12
+1 1:4 2:6 3:3 4:2 5:3 6:5 7:4 8:2 9:3 10:6
```

and so on....

where the numbers on the left of the colon is an 'index' and numbers on the right of the colon  are integers that describe a certain attribute. For each line, if the number on the right of the colon is the same for the same index on another line, I want to store the total amount of +1's and -1's in two separate variables. This is my code so far:

```
for i in lines:
   for word in i:
        if word.find(':')!=-1:
            att = word.split(':', 1)[-1]
            idx = word.split(':', 1)[0]
            for j in lines:
                clas = j.split(' ', 1)[0]
                if word.find(':')!=-1:
                        if idx ==word.split(':', 1)[0]:
                            if att ==word.split(':', 1)[0]:
                                if clas>0:
                                    ifattandyes = ifattandyes+1
                                else:
                                    ifattandno = ifattandno+1
```

My problem is att and idx do not seem to update as I think word.find(':') just finds the first instance of a colon and runs with it. Can anyone help?

EDIT:

The above explanation has been confusing. I'm a bit stubborn about how the count of 1s and -1s is acquired. As each pair on each line is read, I want to search through the data for the number of +1s and -1s that the pair is involved in and store them into 2 separate variables. The reason for doing so is to calculate probabilities of each pair leading to a +1 or -1.

Comment: line 'if att ==word.split(':', 1)[0]:' should read 'if att ==word.split(':', 1)[-1]:'

Comment: Is the 'index' guaranteed to be 1 2 3 4 5 .. 10 in that order on each line?

Comment: @damienfracois yes, but different files will have different indices. But the indices will be the same for each line in a file.

Comment: What is the `+1` in the begging of the line?

Comment: So is it correct to say that you want to count, for each unique combination of attributes, the number of positives and negatives?

Comment: @damienfrancois yes, I think that summarizes this task well.

Comment: @MartinoDino +1 and -1 simply states a positive or negative 'class'. Think of applying for a bank loan. The +1 says you qualify, -1 says you don't and the other values are different attributes which contribute to the +1 and -1.

Comment: So to check: for the three lines there, you'd want (for the +1 case) '1:4': 2, '3:3': 2, '9:2': 1, '4:2': 1, etc?

Comment: @DSM Nope, for 1:4, I want number of +1's to be 2. For 3:3, I want number of +1's to be 2. Same for 7:4.

Comment: Erm -- 2 is the number after '1:4', and 2 is the number after '3:3' in what I wrote above.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @DSM No sorry you were completely right in that respect. I just looked at it in a very closed-minded view. So yes I want +1's and -1s of what you just said. Sorry, sleep deprivation is getting to me....

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion (provided I understand the question correctly) :

```
#!/bin/env python
from collections import defaultdict

positives=defaultdict(int)
negatives=defaultdict(int)

for line in open('data'):
    theclass = line[0:2] == '+1'
    for pair in line[2:].split():
        positives[pair]+=theclass
        negatives[pair]+=not theclass

for key in positives.keys():
    print key, "\t+1:",  positives[key], "\t-1:", negatives[key]
```

Applied to the following data:

```
$ cat data
+1 1:4 2:11 3:3 4:11 5:1 6:13 7:4 8:2 9:2 10:13
-1 1:2 2:7 3:4 4:12 5:3 6:4 7:3 8:12 9:2 10:12
+1 1:4 2:6 3:3 4:2 5:3 6:5 7:4 8:2 9:3 10:6
```

it gives:

```
$ python t.py 
9:2     +1: 1   -1: 1
9:3     +1: 1   -1: 0
8:2     +1: 2   -1: 0
10:6    +1: 1   -1: 0
6:13    +1: 1   -1: 0
10:13   +1: 1   -1: 0
10:12   +1: 0   -1: 1
2:7     +1: 0   -1: 1
2:6     +1: 1   -1: 0
4:11    +1: 1   -1: 0
4:12    +1: 0   -1: 1
4:2     +1: 1   -1: 0
1:2     +1: 0   -1: 1
1:4     +1: 2   -1: 0
3:3     +1: 2   -1: 0
5:1     +1: 1   -1: 0
3:4     +1: 0   -1: 1
5:3     +1: 1   -1: 1
8:12    +1: 0   -1: 1
7:4     +1: 2   -1: 0
7:3     +1: 0   -1: 1
2:11    +1: 1   -1: 0
6:5     +1: 1   -1: 0
6:4     +1: 0   -1: 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the +1s and -1s of each pair as you read them on each line? I understand it might not be efficient but as long as the code runs in under 3 mins it is alright.

Comment: Would adding a `print positives[pair], negatives[pair]` in the loop do what you are asking?

Comment: Anyway, @DSM's answer is more generic and uses less memory.

Comment: I don't want to print it but I want to store only the quantity(number) of +1's and -1's of each pair as I read them on the line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I've got this or not.

```
tot_up = {}; tot_dn = {}
for line in input_file:
    parts = line.split()   # split on whitespace
    up_or_down = parts[0]
    parts = parts[1:]
    if up_or_down == '-1':
        store = tot_dn
    else:
        store = tot_up
    for part in parts:
        store[part] = store.get(part, 0) + 1
print "Total +1s: ", sum(tot_up.values())
print "Total -1s: ", sum(tot_dn.values())
```

What this does not do, but could be done easily enough, is strip out the att:val pairs where no match was found.

But I'm not sure I've understood your requirements properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make this community wiki because it's too close (in spirit, anyway) to an answer already posted, but it has a few advantages:

```
from collections import Counter
with open("datafile.dat") as fp:
    counts = {}
    for line in fp:
        parts = line.split()
        sign, keys = parts[0], parts[1:]
        counts.setdefault(sign, Counter()).update(keys)

all_keys = set().union(*counts.values())
for key in sorted(all_keys):
    print '{:8}'.format(key), 
    print ' '.join('{}: {}'.format(c, counts[c].get(key, 0)) for c in counts)
```

which produces

```
10:12    +1: 0 -1: 1
10:13    +1: 1 -1: 0
10:6     +1: 1 -1: 0
1:2      +1: 0 -1: 1
1:4      +1: 2 -1: 0
[etc.]
```

Note that nowhere is there any reference to `+1` or `-1`; `sign` can really be anything.

Comment: This could be useful, but I would rather the number of +1s and -1s of each pair is stored as a variable as the data is read line by line.....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you referring to the cumulative counts?

Comment: Yes. Meaning when 10:12 is read, it reads through all the data and stores the number of occurrences of 10:12 and -1 that are on one line in one variable and number of occurrences of 10:12 and +1 that are on one line in another variable. I can then use these variables in a probability calculation.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't follow: although you said "yes", what you're referring to isn't a cumulative count.  It sounds like you want to read through the entire data file every time you see 10:12 for some reason, rather than doing it all in one pass.  That will be very slow, because instead of reading through the file once, you'll have to read through it N times, where N is the number of "10:12"-like objects.  Hopefully someone else will be able to help you!

Comment: Sorry, I may have not gotten what you meant by cumulative count correctly. I completely understand that this process will have a high runtime but if the runtime is less than 3 minutes then it is fine. There are 1024 lines. The reason it is worse to do one pass, is that I would then have to store every count of every single pair to a variable to be able to use them in a probability calculation. If it is does N times, the calculations can be made while reusing only 2 variables.... Does that make sense...?

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is in the second line:

```
for word in i:
```

this **iterates over each character**.

You meant to use:

```
for word in i.split():
```